# Why wont my computer start up?

Tags: boot

I cannot get the computer to do anything. I get a code at start up .
6.640648] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to Kill init| exitcode=0x00007f00

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) what version of Ubuntu you are using; ii) what computer this is (laptop? dekstop? what hardware?); iii) What happened before it started doing this. Did you install something? Did you just shut it down and this started happening randomly?

Comment: A screen shot of the *full* error would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are trying to boot from disk. Will it boot from CD/USB? If not you may well have a hardware problem. You could try booting form an Ultimate Boot CD which you would need to create on a working PC but it would then allow you to test the CPU, memory, disk etc. The Ultimate Boot CD is available [here](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). If this CD won't boot either, you have a very sick machine indeed. In this case, check the power supply, replug everything pluggable, but if the problem remains it's probably time to bin it.